# Th 2.41 from Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, metric-spaces

I have a question on Theorem 2.41 on Page 40 of Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, 3rd Edition. Have stated below the theorem, followed by my question.

> Theorem 2.41: If a set $E$ in $R^k$ has one of the following three properties, then it has the other two:
> (a) $E$ is closed and bounded,
> (b) $E$ is compact, and,
> (c) every infinite subset of $E$ has a limit point in $E$.

My question: Is the following situation a counterexample to the assertion that (c) $\implies$ (a)? Let $E$ be the set of all rational numbers in $R^1$. It appears (to me) that every infinite subset of $E$ has a limit point in $E$. Thus, (c) holds in my understanding. However, $E$ is not closed (since $E$ does not include all its limit points), and $E$ is not bounded either. This means that (a) does not hold.

I also see that (similar?) questions have been raised earlier on math.stackexchange.com on the above-mentioned theorem, and been answered. But, no question has cited the above-mentioned "counterexample" (or similar) in my observation. Would greatly appreciate help in understanding where this "counterexample" is wrong (which should be the case in all likelihood I believe). Thanks.

Comment: How do you reconcile these two statements: "every infinite subset of $E$ has a limit point in $E$" and "$E$ does not include all its limit points"?

Comment: In my understanding, if every infinite subset of $E$ has "some" limit point in $E$, it does not follow that $E$ includes all its limit points.

Comment: The infinite set $\{1, 2 , 3 ...\}$ is in E and has no limit point

Comment: For your particular choice of $E$, one of the constructions of $\mathbb R$ involves infinite subsets of the rationals that have no rational limit point.

Comment: I think you are confusing the ability to construct **some** infinite subsets that each have some limit point in $E$ with the statement that **all** infinite subsets have a limit point in $E.$

Comment: @Arctic Char, @ David K: yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every irrational $x$, there is a sequence of rationals that converges to $x$
(and hence  has no rational limit point). E.g. you could use the truncated decimal expansion.

Comment: In your example, $x$ is a limit point of a set, say $F$, of certain rationals. But, it does not mean that $F$ does not have a limit point in $F$. Isn't this correct?

Comment: The only limit point of a sequence converging to $x$ is $x$ itself.

Comment: Yes, that's a very strong argument.